# How to add UIView behind CCGLView (Cocos2d-objc)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to play a video using MPMoviePlayerController and wanted to show it behind the cocos2d assets. I was able to play the video but it appears on top of the cocos2d assets. Cocos2D-ObjC version is 3.5.0.

Here's my code snippet:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer;

CCDirectorIOS *director = (CCDirectorIOS*)[CCDirector sharedDirector];
CC_VIEW *directorView = [director view];
[directorView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[directorView sendSubviewToBack:[moviePlayer view]];
directorView.opaque = NO;
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just for info: there is no way to add it beetween, because cocos2d view controller(with all your images) is a layer added on the directorView.
So cocos2d director is a view controller drawing into a single view, a CCGLView. You can't add a view to a layer, because layers are not views. Layers are just objects used by cocos2d.

As with other views, you can add a view below the cocos2d CCGLView (as a parent or earlier sibling of the GLView) or above the cocos2d CCGLView (as a child or later sibling of the GLView), but not anywhere in-between. Because of this, your UIView can only be logically above or below all Cocos2d drawing.

And for sending back just use:

```
[viewController.view  addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[viewController.view  sendSubviewToBack:moviePlayer.view];
```